# Prove that if $A$ is a principal ring and $p ∈ A$ is irreducible then $(p)$ is maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $A$ be a principal ring and $p ∈ A$ be irreducible.
>   Prove that the ideal $(p)$ is maximal.

Let $a ∈ A$ be non divisible by $p$.

From Bézout, there exist $u, v ∈ A$ such that $up + va = 1$. 
Therefore $(p) + Aa = A$

From there how to prove that $(p)$ is maximal?

Comment: Well assume that $(p) \subset\mathfrak{m}$, then $\mathfrak{m}=(f)$ for a certain $f$ and then $f$ divides $p$ but...

Comment: but p is irreducible so (f) = A which means $(p)$ is maximal

Comment: I guess $A$ is a *principal ideal domain* rather than simply *ring*.

Comment: @egreg: yes principal ring is the same as principal ideal domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a\notin(p)$. Then $(a)+(p)=(b)$, for some $b$. In particular $p\in(b)$, so $p=bc$; since $p$ is irreducible, we conclude that either $b$ or $c$ is invertible.

In the case $b$ is invertible, we have $(a)+(p)=A$.

In the case $c$ is invertible, we have $a=bx$ for some $x$, as $a\in(b)$; then
$$
a=bx=pc^{-1}x\in(p)
$$
which is a contradiction.

Therefore the only ideal properly containing $(p)$ is $A$, which is to say that $(p)$ is maximal.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is PID, and $p $ is irreducible,then $p$ is prime, so $(p)$ is prime ideal. then $(p)$ is maximal ideal.